# what is the kernel ker in the ImageCorrelate of Mathematica Program?

Tags: image-processing

Thank you for consideration. In image Processing with Mathematica Program, it is an order to ImageCorrelate for an image. In this order there is a "kernel ker", I don't know what is that exactly?
Thank you for help

Comment: RTFM: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCorrelate.html